# Read a specific part of an HTML file

Tags: php

I want to load a specific part of an HTML file into a variable like this:

```
$my_file = 'file.html';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'r') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
```

Now, my question is how do I tell PHP which part of the HTML doc I want it to read?

Comment: [Use an HTML parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+html+parser)

Comment: What do you mean by "part"? Are you looking for a specific tag, or pattern of tags?

Comment: @Mansfield He wants a specific node from the document.

Comment: @RobertK I assumed as much but hoped it would prompt him to clarify to improve his question :)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by "part".

The most usefull approaches:

If you know a unique string that starts and finishes that part, e.g.  and , you can load the complete file into a string, [search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) the occurence of the first string, search the occurnece of the second one, then take the [**substring**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) inbetween.

If you have less information, you might need [**regex**](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php).

If your HTML is valid **XML**, load it into an xml object and use xpath or alike... you see, the answer much depends on what you have, and what you want to achieve.